# Using friend function between 2 classes

Tags: c++, friend-function

i've been trying to use the friend function for an assignment, but can't figure out how it works.
every class in the assignment has it's own header and cpp files.
the assignment is building a maze and I want my "Maze" class to use the data members of my "Player" class.
every maze object has 2 players inside it(player array), so i wanted a function that will move a player in the maze and change his coordinates.

side note:
haven't fully understood the friend function it seems , because when I was in practice class, we used the friend function on operator overloading for iostream header, which doesn't make sense to me, because how would i have access to the iostream members if i didn't use the "friend" operator inside the iostream header ? doesn't that mean i can bypass and class and change its' private members ?

this is how i tried to use the function **moveLeft()**, to move a player in the maze:
(i've deleted some of the functions in my code here to highlight my problem - the function i want to use is at the bottom for every included code segment)

this is my Player class :

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

class Player
{
private:
    std::string _name;
    int _highscore;
    int _x, _y;
    bool _isAI;     
public:
    //Constrctors & Destructor
    Player();
    Player(std::string name, int highscore, int xcoor, int ycoor, bool isAI);
    ~Player();

    friend Player& Maze::moveLeft();
};
```

this is the Maze Class :
Header:

```
#pragma once
#include "Player.h"

class Maze
{
private :
    Room** _rooms = new Room*[MAZE_WIDTH];
    Player _player[2];
    Direction roll_Direction(Direction d)const;
public:
    //Constructors & Destructor
    Maze();//Default constructor
    Maze(const Maze& c);//Basic Constrcutor
    ~Maze();//Default Destructor including delete for the allocated memory

    Player& moveLeft();
};
```

CPP:

```
#include "Maze.h"



Maze::Maze()
{
Maze::~Maze()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAZE_WIDTH; i++)
    {
        delete[] this->_rooms[i];
    }
    delete[] this->_rooms;
}

Player& Maze::moveLeft() {
    this->_player[0]._x--;
}
```

Hope my questions make sense,
Thanks,
Lidor

Comment: The side note is completely separate question, but unless you modified `<iostream>` header itself, you did not access any private members of `std::ostream` or `std::istream`. With friend declaration in class `MyClass`, the operator overload gains access to private members of `MyClass` and nothing else.

Comment: About the actual question: is there any external requirement to use `friend` functions here? It seems much more reasonable to provide `Player::moveLeft()` as public function instead of using friendship (which is the strongest coupling type in C++). It will introduce a circular dependency between both classes as well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'd recommend you read C++ guru Scott Meyers' classic article "[How Non-Member Functions Improve Encapsulation](https://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197)". It should answer the questions about when one *should* use a friend function. Here, I think you *should not* use it. It is better to make small, loosely coupled classes. Making them friends, as you are attempting here, tightly couples them since you are tying one class to the implementation (not just the interface) of the other.

Comment: One of the building blocks of OOP is encapsulation. Classes should be designed in such a way that other classes access them through public members only. In your case, I see no reason that would make it impossible.

Comment: The friend attribute is granted by the implementing class, not by the users.

Comment: there wasn't a requirement for the friend functions, i just wanted just specific functions to use the data members because of encapsulation basically. using "friend class Maze" inside the player header works, but then all function in maze get access, and that's something i dont want. 

about the side note, when i did the friend function on "MyClass", i actually gave permission for iostream to use the MyClass data members and not the other way around ?

Comment: @LidorCohen You gave permission to the function that you added to access the private members of your class. This is normally done for `operator<<(std::ostream&, MyClass)` by adding the line `friend ... operator<<...` to your class, so your program has the line `std::out << myobject` and that line calls the operator<<() function.

Comment: difficult to write an answer because apart from the sidenote there is no question. Do you want to know "What is wrong with my code?" or "How can I do XY correctly?" ?

Comment: basically yes, i asked why is my code wrong with regards to the friend function i used - why don't i have access to the Player class data members even though i used "friend"?